# Android game development using unity 3D tutorial

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity 3D. I am planning to develop an android game using Unity 3D, i have searched all over the net for android related tutorials in Unity3D but could not find even one good developer teaching me an app to start up with, so guys please suggest me a site where i can start up.I need android tutorials, not stand alone platform tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [Google](https://www.google.es/#hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=U_VzUML9OsSChQeDr4DwBg&spell=1&q=unity3d+android+tutorial&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=8255192539267d5f&biw=1280&bih=711) or the [Unity3D official documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html).

Comment: I tried reading the official documentation, but could not follow it. So is there any site which has video tutorials for android development.

Comment: @Karthick do you have knowledge programming in Java? do you have knowledge programming in Android? you need to learn in this order Java->Android->Unity3D for Android

Comment: yes i have knowledge of programming both in java and android, and i have been meddling with Unity3D from two weeks, mastered all the controls and did some stand alone platform games. But wen it comes to android apps i am stuck at some stages, no one out there to help me out, that is the reason i am asking for a video tutorial, reading does not help much. We will get a over all basic idea when we read.

Comment: @Karthick IMHO the video tutorials are good to start, but you need to face with text tutorials and official documentation. If you can not understand it well, maybe it is time to take time refreshing old concepts of Java and Android.

Comment: I am ready to read the documentation, no problem in that. Is there any site or any person who usually answers unity related doubts.So that if at all i get stuck anywhere, i can take suggestions and move forward. The reason for me being so persistent on taking someone's help is, its been two weeks i started my work at office and i have not even come up with a basic app, my boss is not satisfied with that

Comment: @Karthick You con just try to use the Unity3D official forum (http://forum.unity3d.com/). Try to ask for support.

Comment: Thank You logoff for your assistance and support. Sure will try mailing them my doubts.

Comment: If you are more specific in where you are getting stuck, posting here on in the forums mentioned above should get you help quicker...

Comment: as of this post. the Official Unity3d websites now Has tutorials (http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). It even have videos to teach you step by step on how to make an android Game in unity. plus Youtube has videos concerning android development as Many android developers nowadays using unity3D provides detailed instructions on how to make them .